# How to combine Dropdown button with TabBar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, tabbar, dropdownbutton

I would like to combine dropdown button with a TabBar I found a solution but the DropDown button is inside the Tab and you have to press on the letter to display the dropdown button and it does not do so when pressing the entire TabBar that is why although it is a solution it is not the best, could you help me improve.

```
void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: TabBarDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const TabBarDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TabBarDemo> createState() => _TabBarDemoState();
}

class _TabBarDemoState extends State<TabBarDemo> {
  String? selectedValue;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      initialIndex: 1,
      length: 4,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('TabBar Widget'),
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              const Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.cloud_outlined)),
              const Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.beach_access_sharp)),
              const Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.brightness_5_sharp)),
              DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                child: DropdownButton<String?>(
                  value: selectedValue,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedValue = value;
                    });
                  },
                  items: ["A", "B", "C"]
                      .map(
                        (e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                          value: e,
                          child: Text(e),
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            const Center(child: Text("It's cloudy here")),
            const Center(
              child: Text("It's rainy here"),
            ),
            const Center(
              child: Text("It's sunny here"),
            ),
            Center(child: Text("TabBar here ${selectedValue ?? "select 1st"}")),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tab Controller and navigate to last tab when the tap event occurs on DropdownButton

```dart
class TabBarDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const TabBarDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TabBarDemo> createState() => _TabBarDemoState();
}

class _TabBarDemoState extends State<TabBarDemo>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  String? selectedValue;

  late final TabController controller = TabController(
    length: 4,
    vsync: this,
  );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('TabBar Widget'),
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: controller,
          tabs: [
            const Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.cloud_outlined)),
            const Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.beach_access_sharp)),
            const Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.brightness_5_sharp)),
            DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
              child: DropdownButton<String?>(
                onTap: () {
                  controller.animateTo(3);
                },
                value: selectedValue,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedValue = value;
                  });
                },
                items: ["A", "B", "C"]
                    .map(
                      (e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: e,
                        child: Text(e),
                      ),
                    )
                    .toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: controller,
        children: [
          const Center(child: Text("It's cloudy here")),
          const Center(
            child: Text("It's rainy here"),
          ),
          const Center(
            child: Text("It's sunny here"),
          ),
          Center(child: Text("TabBar here ${selectedValue ?? "select 1st"}")),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate the time you took to answer me. This solution works but it has two details and I think the question was not well formulated, when you select the fourth tab it should show option A and until it is selected the state “TabBar here select 1st” appears and the second detail is that you must press on the letter or date to be able to display the dropdown button, in conclusion, option "A" should be shown, which is the first, and then allow you to show B and C

Comment: You like to disable/enable the dropdown item  by sequence

Answer (score 0):

I just did Stack on Scaffold and did my own custom container

[1st screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oD8Lz.png)

[2nd example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha22Y.png)

```
void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
     title: 'Material App',
     home: TabBarDemo(),
     );
    }
  }

 class TabBarDemo extends StatefulWidget {
 const TabBarDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 State<TabBarDemo> createState() => _TabBarDemoState();
}

 class _TabBarDemoState extends State<TabBarDemo> {
 String? selectedValue;
 bool buttonDown = false;
 int tabIndex = 0;
 int dropDownindex = 0;
 String dropdownvalue = 'A';
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
 return DefaultTabController(
   initialIndex: 1,
   length: 4,
   child: Stack(
     children: [
       Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(
           title: const Text('TabBar Widget'),
           bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              const Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.cloud_outlined)),
              const Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.beach_access_sharp)),
              const Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.brightness_5_sharp)),
              SizedBox(
                width: width / 3 - 70,
                child: Tab(
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 5,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                        'A',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 3,
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            buttonDown = !buttonDown;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Visibility(
                          visible: dropDownindex == 0,
                          child: Icon(
                            buttonDown
                                ? Icons.keyboard_arrow_up
                                : Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                            //Icons.keyboard_arrow_up,
                            size: 16,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              // DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
              //   child: DropdownButton<String?>(
              //     value: selectedValue,
              //     onChanged: (value) {
              //       setState(() {
              //         selectedValue = value;
              //       });
              //     },
              //     items: ["A", "B", "C"]
              //         .map(
              //           (e) => DropdownMenuItem(
              //         value: e,
              //         child: Text(e),
              //       ),
              //     )
              //         .toList(),
              //   ),
              // ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            const Center(child: Text("It's cloudy here")),
            const Center(
              child: Text("It's rainy here"),
            ),
            const Center(
              child: Text("It's sunny here"),
            ),
            Center(
                child:
                    Text("TabBar here ${dropdownvalue ?? "select 1st"}")),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Visibility(
          visible: buttonDown,
          child: Positioned(
            top: 110 + MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
            left: 115,
            child: AnimatedContainer(
              duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
              curve: Curves.easeInQuint,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(8),
                ),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.16),
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 7,
                    offset: const Offset(0, 3),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              height: 110,
              width: 110,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, bottom: 12, left: 16),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        buttonDown = false;
                        dropdownvalue = 'A';
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'A',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 13,
                        color: const Color(0xFF1A1A1A),
                        height: 1.2,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 16,
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        buttonDown = false;
                        dropdownvalue = 'B';
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'B',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 13,
                        color: const Color(0xFF1A1A1A),
                        height: 1.2,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 16,
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        buttonDown = false;
                        dropdownvalue = 'C';
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'C',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 13,
                        color: const Color(0xFF1A1A1A),
                        height: 1.2,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate the time you took to answer me. I apologize for not formulating but the only detail that this solution has is that you must press on the letter or the icon so that it can display the dropdown button and it should be displayed when you press on the tab